# How to remotely invoke a device admin policy?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, device-admin

What I want to do, have a [BroadcastReceiver] that listens to any incoming SMS, that when the incoming SMS has a certain keyword, it will pass over to device admin and invoke the required policy.

I have created a BroadcastReceiver that listen to SMS and pop a toast, and it works fine. Then I created a device admin app following this guide: http://marakana.com/s/post/1291/android_device_policy_administration_tutorial, and its working as it should. But when I include that SMS receiver together with device admin, it crashes whenever an sms comes in. Also, I'm unable to pass the string that I want to use from the SMS receiver to my device admin app in order to invoke the required policy.

This is my device admin

```
public class AppPolicyActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

static final int ACTIVATION_REQUEST = 47;
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName appPolicy;
ToggleButton toggleBtn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_layout);

    toggleBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleBtn);
    toggleBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    appPolicy = new ComponentName(this, AppPolicyReceiver.class);


// The commented code below made my app crash during installation
/*      Intent intent;
    try {
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            intent = getIntent();
            String keyword = intent.getStringExtra("keyword");
            if (keyword.equals("LOCK")) {
                receivedSMS(keyword);
            } else if (keyword.equals("WIPE")) {
                receivedSMS(keyword);
            }
            keyword = "";
            intent = null;
            finish();
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {} */
}

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isChecked) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, appPolicy);
        intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Activate the application to use its features");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
    } else {
        mDPM.removeActiveAdmin(appPolicy);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (requestCode) {
    case ACTIVATION_REQUEST:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            toggleBtn.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            toggleBtn.setChecked(false);
        }
        return;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public void receivedSMS(String keyword) {
    // Lock
    if (keyword.equals("LOCK")) {
        mDPM.lockNow();
    } 
    // Wipe/delete
    else if (keyword.equals("WIPE")) {
        mDPM.wipeData(ACTIVATION_REQUEST);
    }
}
}
```

This is the device admin receiver class

```
public class AppPolicyReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.disabletext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDisabled(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.enabletext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onEnabled(context, intent);
}
}
```

this is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.fyp.mobilesecurity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name="AppPolicyActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- appPolicyReceiver -->
    <receiver android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" android:name="AppPolicyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED"/>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:resource="@xml/app_admin" 
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"/>
    </receiver>

    <!-- SMSReceiver -->
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="SMSReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

and this is from log, as you can see my receiver is not even started.

```
11-17 21:06:52.300: E/AndroidRuntime(375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.fyp.mobilesecurity.SMSReceiver: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I just realize that its returning an exception, so I enclosed my receiver in try/catch block, and now its working fine.

Comment: To add, should I pass the parameter from my broadcast receiver->device admin receiver->device admin activity or broadcast receiver->device admin activity ?

Comment: how to declare Broadcast Receiver together with Device admin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to see what's causing the NullPointerException in SMSReceiver. The stacktrace will have the line number.

Comment: Yeah, I just realize that today. I have enclosed them in a try/catch block and now its working! Wish I could have found it sooner.